# Notification Title Differs from Edited Question Title

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, notifications, android-app

As you can see in the screenshot below, the title of the question in the notification differs from the actual title of the question. Here is an explanation of what I did:

- When I asked the question [Why Does a Label Inside an Input Trigger a Click Event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19249209/738262),  I originally entered the title as "Why Does **This** Label Inside an Input Trigger a Click Event". After a few comments and I accepted the answer, I noticed I used the word "this" instead of "a" and edited the title. After editing the title, I noticed it did not change in the app notification. I figured I'd give it a little time before asking this question (it's been 12 hours now) in case it took a little while to update. The notification title still shows the pre-edited title.

The only thing I can think of that would be a possible cause is that the answer/comments were posted prior to me editing the title. I figured if this was the case, my profile [activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/738262/brian?tab=activity) would work the same. I checked my activity and the title of the question is the correct (or edited) title on the answer/comments.

It is worth noting that I am not sure whether or not the question title would update in my app notifications if another comment was posted (since none were posted after I edited it). I guess it's also worth noting that when I click on the notification and it takes me to the actual question, the title in the question is correct (as you can see in the screenshot).

Is my thought that it differs because I edited it after those comments were posted correct, or should it be updated to reflect my edited title?

[image: Title in notification differs from the actual title]

Please let me know if any additional details/explanations are needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notifications do not get updated dynamically. They use whatever title the question had at the time the notification was generated (it gets stored with the notification, not looked up every time you load the notification). This is not specific to the Android App either; it occurs for *all* notifications even on the main site itself.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the quick response and explanation!